# Send Name of Param to Controler by Change function. Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to make some string from few inputs . I want to send name of input (name of element of HTML) as second parameter in function.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="programSearched" name="programSearched"(ngModelChange)="stringBuilderOnChageMaker(programSearched,??programSearched.name??)" </input>
```

something like this because i have different input with same onchange action, and  i want to know with input 
is calling my method.

```
stringBuilderOnChageMaker(value, type) {
    if (type == X) {
    ...
    } else if (type == Y) {
    ...
    }
}
```

The one solution is to send somthing as secound paramiter like "program" or 1 but it is not look good , it will look better if i will send id or name of element.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `$event` parameter to your change method. This will give you the object that's changed. Assuming your object has a name field it would look like:

**html**

```
(ngModelChange)="stringBuilderOnChageMaker(programSearched, $event)"
```

**ts**

```
stringBuilderOnChageMaker(value, event) {
    console.log(event); // check what this logs
    const name = event.name;

    if (name == X) {
    ...
    } else if (name == Y) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no name field in event i was trying this :( No name No id

Answer (score 0):

I know, some time passed, but today I had same problem. I solved it like this:

html:

```
(change)="saveChange(product, $event)"
```

ts:

```
public saveChange(product, event) {

    const name = event.currentTarget.name;
    //..
}
```

Tested on angular 7.0.6